# Successive sequence terms $2m - 8$, $2m + 4$, and $5m - 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is successive sequence  $2m - 8$, $2m + 4$, and $5m - 2$ is a valid sequence?

I would assume this is geometric sequence, because it doesn't have constant intervals between terms, but I can't see any pattern here here either.

How can I check if this sequence is valid, and if so - how can I find value of $m$ in this situation?

Comment: It is a valid sequence for all $m$ - it doesn't have to be arithmetic or geometric.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that our sequence is GP then solve $$(2m+4)^2=(5m-2)(2m-8)$$ and check that $$(2m+4)(5m-2)(2m-8)\neq0.$$

If you want that this sequence is AP then solve
$$2(2m+4)=5m-2+2m-8.$$

Without some more given it's just sequence.

Comment: thanks for reply! so if this is GP, than m is either 0 or 10? and since it can't be 0, it's 10. is that correct? Is it possible to tell what the next term will be from this point?

Answer (score 0):

There are many sequences that are neither arithmetic nor geometric.  All you need for a sequence to be valid is for there to be just one value for each term.  If you are given that it is an arithmetic sequence you can determine the value of $m$.  The first two terms have a difference of $4$, so the last two must as well, giving $(5m-2)-(2m+4)=4,m=\frac {10}3$.  Similarly, if you are told that it is geometric you can solve for $m$.  Otherwise, you can just leave it as is.  You don't know if there are more terms or what the are if they exist.